# userTokenDetails [ 'NoAccess' ] for shopify webhooks

Tags: shopify

In Shopify for app mandatory webhooks such as Customer data request endpoint, Customer data erasure endpoint and  Shop data erasure endpoint. 
I got as **userTokenDetails [ 'NoAccess' ]**

Even though, my app have order and customer permission

APP PERMISSIONS
This app can access and modify your store‘s data.

Read products, variants, and collections

Read orders, transactions, and fulfillments

Read customer details and customer groups

Read price rules

Read all orders

This app has access to personal information such as:

Customer names, e-mail addresses, phone numbers, physical addresses, geolocations, IP addresses, and browser user agents

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the App setup in your Partner Dashboard, you will see that you setup those endpoints **in the App setup** not as part of your App itself. So it makes sense that your attempt to POST to those endpoints results in **NoAccess**.

So login to your partner account, and paste in the endpoints for those webhooks there.

Comment: Yes, I've already gave the endpoints on my partner account . Kindly see this screenshot https://prnt.sc/mhqqsf

Comment: Hi, david i am not clear . I already place the end point url in my partner app setup . shall i need to do anything further to activate the endpoints ? . if any thing need pls elaborate the answer